# URLEncoder crashes my app (It was actually a too early initialized variable causing the crash)

Tags: java, android, urlencode

I know, I am the "Asker"-type of user in here... Well...
This code crashes my app, it is part of a dialog button. (Inside a method)

```
                    try
                    {
                        eq = URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                    {throw new AssertionError("Your system is messed up. UTF-8 is always a supported encoder, but it failed on your system.",e);}
```

Doesn't matter where I am putting this, my app crashes on start.
These lines of code initialize

```
public String eq;
```

and then I do this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + eq));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

If I only put "http://www.google.com" in the Intent, and leave away eq and don't execute the URLEncoder (don't have it in the code at all), it works. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? q has "test search %s in it, which is getting replaced with the device model (GT-I9100 in my case) and then the variable eq should be "test+search+GT-I9100" or something like this in it.

My Logcat says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   
instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mm.rootchecker/com.mm.rootchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2421)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:390)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mm.rootchecker.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:128)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
08-03 11:47:20.242 20099 20099 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can we see the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Fustigador Wait, I'll edit my post with it.

Comment: I would rather bet, that it would be something to do with varargs `%s`, but the stack trace will hopefully show the cause. Maybe the format is done after URL encode, that itself might introduce ' %XX`

Comment: @JoopEggen No, that can't be the cause, because I use "getString(R.string.searchquery1, android.os.Build.MODEL);", and if I remove URLEncoder, it works.

Comment: I couldn't get a stacktrace. That's bad. e.getStackTrace() isn't executed...

Comment: Can you post the full code you are testing instead of just a couple separate snippets? Also, replace the `AssertionError` with a `Log.e("whatevertag", "whatevermsg", e)` so it's possible to capture the stack trace in logcat.

Comment: Try harder. Your question isn't answerable without it. Try `e.printStackTrace()` as the first line of the `catch` block. NB There is no initialization here, other than to `null.`

Comment: (I'll add it to my post)

Comment: I think the value of `q` is null, in that case `URLEncoder.encode` method will throw `nullpointerException`

Comment: Please add the whole thing, not just the bits you like. There is no evidence of an `AssertionError` or `UnsupportedEncodingException` there.

Comment: @SachinGupta If I let it be shown in a toast, it isn't null.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `URLEncoder.` The code you have posted does not throw that exception. Read it. It comes from a `getResources()` call elsewhere.

Comment: The stack trace shows clearly you are executing getResources() method on a null object...since getResources() is a Context method, I would say your Context object is null.

Comment: @Fustigador But I don't have getResources call in my code. But it might be inside the URLEncoder class.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with getResources(), I was trying to initialize a variable before the onCreate() method. Look at laalto's answer, it really helped me.

Comment: If it was inside the `URLEncoder` class, the `URLEncoder` class would appear in the stack trace. It doesn't. QED

Comment: @EJP I know, but it was my mistake. I tried to initialize the variable "q" before onCreate() ia executed. That's why the NPE happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the stacktrace:

```
  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:390)
  at com.mm.rootchecker.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:128)
```

You cannot access resources before `onCreate()` of the activity lifecycle. Construction phase `<init>` e.g. initializing member variables is too early.

Comment: In other words - do your thing in `onCreate`, not in the constructor of your activity.

Comment: Oh. I tried to initialize the variable "q" inside the same method as the eq method, and now it works. I am really overlooking the most simple things, I really did try to initialize it before the onCreate() method. Thank you!